# Change color property of Animated Container on button press

Tags: flutter

I want the color of animated container to repeatedly change according to the colors given  in the array. Button will be pressed only one time.

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPageState createState() => MyPageState();
}

class MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  var arr = [Colors.green,Colors.blue];
  Color _color = Colors.red;
  double _width = 100.0;
  double _height = 100.0;
  BoxShape _boxshape = BoxShape.circle;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
          children:<Widget>[ Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: AnimatedContainer(duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      width: _width,
      height: _height,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: _boxshape,
        color: _color
      ),
      ),

          ),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            int i = 0;
            while(i<=1) {
              setState(() {
                _color = arr[i];
              });
              if(i==1)
              {
                i = 0;
              }
              i++;
            }
          },
          child: Text('Start'),)
          ],
    );
  }
}
```

RaisedButton doesn't work if I do like above.
If I remove loop and give

```
_color = Colors.green
```

it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i" is always 1 after the second loop in your code.
And add wait.

```
onPressed: () async {
  int i = 0;
  while (i <= 1) {
    setState(() {
      _color = arr[i];
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    if (i == 1) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
},
```